# AND/OR in Python?

Tags: python, logic

I know that the `and` and `or` expressions exist in python, but is there any `and/or` expression? Or some way to combine them in order to produce the same effect as a `and/or` expression?

my code looks something like this:

```
if input=="a":        
    if "a" or "á" or "à" or "ã" or "â" in someList:            
        someList.remove("a") or someList.remove("á") or someList.remove("à") or someList.remove("ã") or someList.remove("â")
```

with this, I mean that if the user inputs "a" and any type of "a" is included in a previously defined list, can I have all the types of "a" removed from a given list?

python tells me that there is a problem in:

```
someList.remove("a") or someList.remove("á") or someList.remove("à") or someList.remove("ã") or someList.remove("â")
```

he tells me: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: Give us a truth table describing the possible inputs, and what results you expect.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As [Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149756/577088)'s answer explains, `or` *is* "and/or". But `or` doesn't work with `in` the way you use it above. You have to say `if "a" in someList or "á" in someList or...`. Or better yet,

```
if any(c in someList for c in ("a", "á", "à", "ã", "â")):
    ...
```

That's the answer to your question as asked.

#### Other Notes

However, there are a few more things to say about the example code you've posted. First, the chain of `someList.remove... or someList remove...` statements here is unnecessary, and may result in unexpected behavior. It's also hard to read! Better to break it into individual lines:

```
someList.remove("a")
someList.remove("á")
...
```

Even that's not enough, however. As you observed, if the item isn't in the list, then an error is thrown. On top of that, using `remove` is very slow, because every time you call it, Python has to look at every item in the list. So if you want to remove 10 different characters, and you have a list that has 100 characters, you have to perform 1000 tests.

Instead, I would suggest a very different approach. Filter the list using a `set`, like so:

```
chars_to_remove = set(("a", "á", "à", "ã", "â"))
someList = [c for c in someList if c not in chars_to_remove]
```

Or, change the list in-place without creating a copy:

```
someList[:] = (c for c in someList if c not in chars_to_remove)
```

These both use list comprehension syntax to create a new list. They look at every character in `someList`, check to see of the character is in `chars_to_remove`, and if it is not, they include the character in the new list.

This is the most efficient version of this code. It has two speed advantages:

1. It only passes through `someList` once. Instead of performing 1000 tests, in the above scenario, it performs only 100.
2. It can test all characters with a single operation, because `chars_to_remove` is a `set`. If it `chars_to_remove` were a `list` or `tuple`, then each test would really be 10 tests in the above scenario -- because each character in the list would need to be checked individually.

Comment: what does `someList[:]` actually mean?

Comment: @JNat, it's known as "slice assignment", and it assigns to a "slice" of a list the values in a given sequence. So for example, say we have `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`. Then we do `a[0:2] = [3, 4]`. Now the value of `a` is `[3, 4, 3, 4]`. As with other kinds of slicing, leaving out an index means "from the beginning" or "to the end." And the sequence to be assigned can be of a different length from the slice. So we can do this, `a[:2] = [2]`, and then the value of `a` is `[2, 3, 4]`. Finally, we can leave both off, and do something like this: `a[:] = [11, 12, 13]`, which overwrites all values.

Comment: Better to use set literal with {} than cast a tuple to a set with `set()` for performance.

Answer (score 15):

`or` is not exclusive (e.g. [`xor`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor)) so `or` is the same thing as `and/or`.

Answer (score 15):

`x and y` returns true if both `x` and `y` are `true`.
`x or y` returns if either one is `true`.

From this we can conclude that `or` contains `and` within itself unless you mean `xOR` (or except if `and` is true)

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for...

```
a if b else c
```

Or perhaps you misunderstand Python's `or`? `True or True` is `True`.

Answer (score 4):

For the updated question, you can replace what you want with something like:

```
someList = filter(lambda x: x not in ("a", "á", "à", "ã", "â"), someList)
```

`filter` evaluates every element of the list by passing it to the lambda provided. In this lambda we check if the element is not one of the characters provided, because these should stay in the list.

Alternatively, if the items in `someList` should be unique, you can make `someList` a set and do something like this:

```
someList = list(set(someList)-set(("a", "á", "à", "ã", "â")))
```

This essentially takes the difference between the sets, which does what you want, but also makes sure every element occurs only once, which is different from a list. Note you could store `someList` as a set from the beginning in this case, it will optimize things a bit.

Comment: with the `filter` option, it evaluates every `x` in the list, and keeps them if it is not contained in the characters provided. Is this it?

Comment: @JNat: indeed, that is what it does.

Comment: this one didn't work... i think it TURNED the list into a filter, instead of filtering it... is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
for m in ["a", "á", "à", "ã", "â"]:
    try:
        somelist.remove(m)
    except:
        pass
```

Just for your information. `and` and `or` operators are also using to return values. It is useful when you need to assign value to variable but you have some pre-requirements

operator `or` returns first not null value

```
#init values
a,b,c,d = (1,2,3,None)

print(d or a or b or c)
#output is value of variable `a` - 1

print(b or a or c or d)
#output is value of variable `b` - 2
```

Operator `and` returns last value in the sequence if any of the members don't have `None` value. If they have at least one `None` value we get is `None`

```
print(a and d and b and c)
#output: None

print(a or b or c)
#output is value of c - 3
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if input == 'a':
    for char in 'abc':
        if char in some_list:
            some_list.remove(char)
```

Comment: I think the original question is more related to how to express "and/or" statement rather than removing some elements from a list.