# Python logic mnemonic

Tags: python, boolean-logic

In answer to [a question about Python and/or logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149747/and-or-in-python), Spacetoast wrote:

`x and y returns true if both x and y are true.`

`x or y returns if either one is true.`

I manage to confuse myself by using "or" when it should have been "and". Without having to drawing up truth tables, is there an mnemonic to help remember the correct usage of and/or?

Comment: I would have thought that the best mnemonic for remembering how "and" and "or" work (for English speakers at least) is remembering what the words "and" and "or" mean in English. The words were not chosen to be difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a true Mnemonic, but NOAH has helped my students in the past.

How many inputs must be true?

None => Nor

One => Or

All => And

Honestly => Heed the truth tables

To be honest the skill of being able to use a truth table is worth persevering with.  (Note there is not a NOR operator in python, its a Not-or).

Comment: `true NAND false` is true though. None should be "nor".

Comment: damned Monday morning brain on a Tuesday - Thanks @kennytm - edited.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion from the pointed answer to that question come from the fact that he says the `OR` contains `AND` which is true in your case. There's is nothing to remember here, if you use `or` operator and *at least one of the two expressions is True* then it returns `True` if  *none of the two expressions are True* it returns `False`

This means that if both `x` and `y` are `True` the `or` will be `True` too because as soon as the first expression `x` is `True` there's no need for evaluating the second one.

On the other hand, if you're using `and` and the first expression doesn't evaluate to True, there's no need to evaluate the second one, since it's impossible for both of them to be True anymore.

[image]

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph: this is different from `xor`, which *does* literally mean "either one *or* the other – but not both". A bit like asking, "what do you want for dessert, ice cream or pudding?" "I want both!" – mum should have asked "ice cream `xor` pudding".

Answer (score 1):

there is no need of mnemonic for this
remember this by a simple concept:

or -> any one true
and -> all true

true or false = True

true and false = False