# Please explain the output of this python code

Tags: python

Here the code.

```
a = False
if a == True or True:
   print "Hell yeah,I'm genius"
else:
   print "shit,I am a fool"
```

Output is '`Hell yeah,I'm genius`'

Comment: There is very little to explain here. Anything `or True` will evaluate to `True`, meaning the first line will print.

Comment: @karin Thank you... I'm a python newbie.So I have assigned "False" to "a" isn't that mean a is 0 ? And True or True==1 ? Then i thought shit,I am a fool is the output..

Comment: The problem is with the "or True". Remove this part and you will get "shit I am a fool". Due to "or True"  every time the if condition is met and you are getting "Hell yeah I',m genius"

Comment: Please go through this link for more info AND/OR in python - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149747/and-or-in-python/10149756#10149756

Comment: @DineshPundkar Is there a big difference between "True" and "True or True"..Aren't they both equal to boolean "1" ?

Comment: `False or True` will evaluate to `True`. So, even though `a == True` is False, the `or True` will make the entire condition `True` regardless.

Comment: what your `if` condition is saying is "if the value of A is True, or if True is True, print 'hell yeah I'm a genius'".  Truth is, unsurprisingly, always True.

Comment: @Karin Thank you very much for your explanation...@n1c9 Thank you...!!!

Comment: Addint to @Karin above comment . In case of "a==True or True", first "a==True" is evaluated which will return False. Then, remaining will be "False or True". Therefore, False or True will evaluate to True.

Comment: @DineshPundkar Thank you very much..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a ==True or True
```

Consider True is 1 and 0 is False.

Since a is set to False (a=False in first statement of code), the first part 'a==True' i.e.  0 ==1 will return 0 (False).

Then remaining will be False or True since 'a==True' is False.
So it will be like 0 or 1 (False or True).

We know that

- 0 AND 0 = 0
- 1 AND 0 = 0
- 1 AND 1 = 1
- 0 OR 0 = 0
- 0 OR 1 = 1
- 1 OR 1 = 1

So in your case, 0 OR 1 will result to 1 i.e. True.

**Summary :**

```
a == True or True => False or True => True
```

That's why "Hell yeah,I'm genius" will be printed.

Answer (score -1):

Anything True , it will run that section ...

```
if True:

   print "Hell yeah,I'm genius"

else:

   print "shit,I am a fool"
```

This one also returns `"Hell yeah,I'm genius"`

Comment: @DineshPundkar If you're in Python2, then you can say `True = False` before running this example, and it'll give you the desired output ;)